# Как получить на сервере GET-запрос Ajax  и обработать в PHP?

Tags: ajax, php

Как получить на сервере запрос `get` Ajax и обработать в php?
Например, есть кусок кода:

```
request.open("GET","kakoy_to.php?infa = " + escape(infa),true);
```

Как эту инфу обработать на сервере? 
Проверка `if(isset($_GET['infa']))` возвращает `false`. 
Помогите, пожалуйста. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: В самом php нужно построить цельный зарос! Не войдя в квартиру - в туалет не попадешь!

?infa кввартира то что после = туалет)))

Answer (score 1):

```
"kakoy_to.php?infa=" + escape(infa)
```

Вот так) Пробелы в адресной строке - это часть либо переменной, либо ее имени. Т.е. вы получали

```
$_GET['infa '] = ' данные'; // $_GET['infa'] = null
```